# Network objects behaving differently when using a remote server compared to localhost

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm dynamically loading avatars from Ready Player Me into unity when spawning a player object (netocde for gameobjects), and using nuitrack to then control the avatar. In order to move the avatar, in the player prefab I have some transforms (with non server-authoritative network transforms) that I then set as the parents to the bones I want to move. When testing localhost, the avatar moves normally as it should, but when testing with a remote server, the movement of the arms is inverted, no idea why.

I expected the remote server to behave the same way as the localhost, but for some reason it's inverting movement of some transforms

Answer (score 0):

Nuitrack developer here.
As of moment we don't have a particular tutorial with ReadyPlayerMe, but plan to add it to SDK soon.
If you have some specific issue with a Nuitrack, our community forum could be good place to go, as it contains a lot of information already and we are answering there regularly.

Comment: Hey! I was able to "fix" the issue by not rotating the player object on spawn as I was doing, everything is fine now. I'm now trying to rotate him without messing with the bones. Looking forward for the SDK update!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).